# Simplifying Locating an element in a list, perhaps using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
class TestClass
{
    public string StringValue {
        get; set;
    }
    public int IntValue {
        get; set;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    private readonly List<TestClass> MyList;

    public MainClass()
    {
        MyList = new List<TestClass>();
    }

    public void RemoveTestClass(string strValue)
    {
         int ndx = 0;

         while (ndx < MyList.Count)
         {
             if (MyList[ndx].StringValue.Equals(strValue))
                 break;
             ndx++;
         }
         MyList.RemoveAt(ndx);
    }

    public void RemoveTestClass(int intValue)
    {
         int ndx = 0;

         while (ndx < MyList.Count)
         {
             if (MyList[ndx].IntValue == intValue)
                 break;
             ndx++;
         }
         MyList.RemoveAt(ndx);
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a simpler way, perhaps using LINQ, to replace the `while` loops in the 2 `RemoveTestClass` functions, rather then iterating through each element, like I'm doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx):

```
myList.RemoveAt(MyList.FindIndex(x => x.StringValue == strValue));
```

You may also want to handle the case where the element is not found:

```
int i = myList.FindIndex(x => x.StringValue == strValue);
if (i != -1)
{
    myList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: You could also use [List.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and  `List.Find`instead of  `List.FindIndex` couldn't you?

Comment: @TimSchmelter But find will throw an execption if it doesn't find a matching item.

Comment: @Fischermaen: But @Mark has als handled the case that `i=-1`. You could also handle the case that `List.Find` is `null`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, you can do that but in the worst cast it would require iterating over the entire list twice. (Sorry I misunderstood your comment the first time I read it).

Comment: That makes sense, then it's better to use `FindIndex`

Answer (score 3):

Simplest possible way I can think is finding first item, which matches the criteria and then use List.Remove to do it:

```
myList.Remove(myList.FirstorDefault(x=>x.StringValue == stringValue))
```

because `Remove` doesn't throw an exception when it can't find the item, above works fine. except you permited to have null values in list, which will be deleted, and I think it's not so good to have them in list.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in that way:

```
public void RemoveTestClass(string strValue) 
{ 
     MyList.RemoveAll(item => item.StringValue.Equals(strValue));
}
```

and:

```
public void RemoveTestClass(int intValue) 
{ 
     MyList.RemoveAll(item => item.IntValue == intValue);
}
```

Update:

If you only want to remove the first occurrance:

```
public void RemoveTestClass(int intValue) 
{ 
     var itemToRemove = MyList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.InValue == intValue);
     if (itemToRemove != null)
     {
         MyList.Remove(itemToRemove);
     }
}
```

Comment: RemoveAll will remove all the items, not just the first.