# Unable to remove the item with .Remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I am trying to remove the item from the arraylist but item is not getting remove, I am not getting any error remove is not working.

```
protected void ibtnMoveUp_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList ImgArry = new ArrayList();
        ImgArry.Add(SelImgId);
        ImgArry.Add(SelImgpath);//image name
        ImgArry.Add(SelImgName);//image path
        List<int> t1 = new List<int>();
        if (Imgarry1 != null)
            t1 = Imgarry1;//Imaarry1 is the type List<int>
        t1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ImgArry[0]));
        Imgarry1 = t1;
        List<ArrayList> t = new List<ArrayList>();
        if (newpath.Count > 0)// newpath is the type List<ArrayList> nd creating the viewstate
            t = newpath;
        t.Remove(ImgArry);//Item is not getting remove
        newpath = t;
        for (int i = 0; i < newpath.Count; i++)
        {
            ArrayList alst = newpath[i];
            newtb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(alst[0]), alst[1].ToString(), alst[2].ToString(), i);

        }
        dlstSelectedImages.DataSource = newtb;
        DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Here is an answer from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907475/simplifying-locating-an-element-in-a-list-perhaps-using-linq/7907500#7907500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam Houldsworth is saying write but I have done with some different way nd my code is bellow

i have removed t.Remove(ImgArry); this line and added

```
             List<ArrayList> temp = new List<ArrayList>(t.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < t.Count; i++)
                {
                    ArrayList al = t[i];
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(al[0]) != Convert.ToInt32(ImgArry[0]))
                        temp.Add(al);
                }
                t = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove is working, but the item you are passing is not passing equality tests with any item in the list.

Removing by providing an object will try to test equality (usually via `.Equals()`) of that item with all items in the list until one is found, then it is removed.  If it doesn't find any, it won't cause an exception.

Comment: will you plz tell me how could i remove the item

Comment: @Rocky your sample code doesn't demonstrate the problem.  `newpath` is conditionally assigned to `t`, which may or may not have any items in it of unknown type.  Your question is currently not directly answerable.  I can only answer why `Remove` is "failing".

Comment: when i am manually checking item is not getting removed from list, and my equality is pass

Answer (score 0):

`ImgArry` is a local variable, reference type. As the default behaviour on reference types for `Equals()` is indeed `ReferenceEquals()`, you can't achieve it, because the instance you just created can't have been put in your container in anyway.

You must search the item you wan't to remove first. E.g. : `t.Find(a => a[0] == SelImgId)`

Then you can `t.Remove()` the previously returned item.